# method URLDownloadToFile in c++ not downloading?

Tags: c++, download

I am new to c++ and I am making a application. In the menu I have an option where you can download Apple Cleaner and clean your system. However when I try download it using this code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

void Clean()
{
    string cleaning = "Opening Apple Cleaner...";

    int f = 0;
    while (cleaning[f] != '\0')
    {
        cout << cleaning[f];
        Sleep(10);
        f++;
    };
    int choice2 = 0;

    const wchar_t* URL = L"https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1072743268678381651/1099243281474387979/applecleaner.exe";
    const wchar_t* Path = L"C:\\Windows\\System\\applecleaner.exe";

    if (S_OK == URLDownloadToFile(NULL, URL, Path, 0, NULL))
    {
        cout << "\n\nApple Cleaner has been downloaded\n" << endl;
        
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
```

It doesn't download and I can't find it in the path that I entered. However it prints "Apple Cleaner has been downloaded".

I tried changing the url and path, put it into a different sln, and used "string" instead of "const wchar_t*" and still, no luck. Could anyone please help me out? Like I said earlier, I am new to c++ so feel free to correct or suggest anything.

Comment: My guess would be that you don't have permission to write into the windows system folder

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)  `URLDownloadToFile returns S_OK even if the file cannot be created and the download is canceled.`

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that the issue wasn't with the code, it was because I forgot to run the file as admin. Thanks for you reply